# How to write Numpy matrix in different column

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I want to write Matrix in three different column in csv format as shown in pictures.[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iv9O.png)

[solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpYVF.png)

I have tried following code:

```
   with open('outfilesss1.csv', "a") as f:
    for gh in _GRAPH:
        np.savetxt(f,gh,fmt='%.0f',)
        f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

Comment: How do you intend to use such a file?  Even if you could write it, loading it would a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for numpy's reshape function. Here an example:

```
a = np.arange(12)
dim0 = len(a)//3
b = a.reshape((dim0, 3))
print(f"Before reshape:\n {a}")
print(f"After reshape:\n {b}")
```

output:

```
Before reshape:
 [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11]
After reshape:
 [[ 0  1  2]
 [ 3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11]]
```

Keep in mind to make sure that your initial list is dividable by 3.

Then, to save b to a csv file, run:

```
with open('out.csv', "w") as f:
    np.savetxt(f, b, delimiter=',')
```

Hope this helps! If not, please comment.